# Xamarin control in a UIView

Tags: android, ios, xamarin

It is possible to use Xamarin Form and C# to create a control that is being used in Android View and iOS UiView?  I don't want to use any knowledge of UIKit and Android UI for this task. The idea is to have x-platform code that requires no knowledge of those native platforms.

I want to use the created UI Control is native iOS/Android projects built using Android Studio and xCode. ** host app project not Xamarin.

If this is possible, what is the memory footprint loading Xamarin frameworks into iOS and Android app?

Comment: This is what Xamarin.Forms was created for: https://www.xamarin.com/forms

You can get started here: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/getting-started/

Comment: I think you are not understanding the question - I want to use the created Xamarin UI Control is native iOS/Android projects built using Android Studio and xCode. I don't want to build Xamarin Form projects and use C# for the entire project.

I have existing Swift project as host, I want to use a control built with Xamarin. Possible?

Comment: No, this is not possible(At least in the case of it being supported). The opposite which is (Taking existing Obj C/Java libraries into a Xamarin project) is possible however via Binding Projects: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c/ https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/